# Android Handler every X seconds in Service

Tags: android, service, handler

I have a problem with an handler that has to be executed every X seconds inside a Service. Basically the timing is not precise at all, some times the handler is called every X seconds, then nothing for 30 seconds and then many calls in a single second.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);


private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
        public void run() {

            new postToCassandra().execute();

            handler.postDelayed(this, CassandraPostBatch.TIME_INTERVAL);
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is a UI thread what you are implementing, it will not work in `service` because android service needs **non ui thread**

Comment: This might be due to the Asynchronous task you are using, postToCassandra. The handler will fire in that time interval but the task might cause a delay. Where did you add the log that posts the time. Maybe you should rather look at using a TimerTask

Comment: In fact I discovered that is the task which is delaying. It is an HttpPost task

Comment: Have a look at the answer that I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your asynchronous task causing the delay.

**Just a note**, your scheduling implementation looks a little strange. Maybe you should try something like this, could prove to be more effective.

```
private static final int TIMER_RATE = 30000;
private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 0;
private Timer timer;

private void startTimer() {
    cancelTimer();
    scheduleTimer();
}

private void scheduleTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new postToCassandra().execute();
        }
    }, TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_RATE);
}

private void cancelTimer() {
    if (timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
}
```

and then just call `startTimer()`. You could also implement a listener in your `PostToCassandra` task that will notify the `TimerTask` when it is done so that it can start with the next post.